# Enum binding with converter

Tags: wpf, xaml, enums

I have `Languages` enum. And My `Model.Translations` is representing different languages translations:

```
public ObservableCollection<LanguageValue> Translations { get; set; }
public class LanguageValue
    {
        public Language Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

I want my view to have label - textbox list for each item in Translations.
But in Label I want to have something like `"Caption ({0})"`, where parameter is Language name (enum to string representation). This text itself is coming from Resources.

Something like:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Translations}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="5,2,5,2">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="70*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ItemLabel" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                             Text="{Binding Path=Key, Converter=languageConverter, ConverterParameter={x:Static res:Resources.lblCaption}}" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ItemText" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                             Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </Grid>                        
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

My LanguageConverter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Language), typeof(string))]
public class LanguageToDisplayConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type t, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.Format(parameter.ToString(), ((Language)value).ToString());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type t, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //I guess I don't need this anyway?
        return null;
    }
}
```

But I've got error:

```
The TypeConverter for "IValueConverter" does not support converting from a string.
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should declare your converter as a resource (in a Window, or app-wide in App.xaml):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <views:LanguageToDisplayConverter x:Key="languageConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

and use accordingly:

```
Text="{Binding Path=Key, Converter={StaticResource languageConverter},  ...
```

the error "The TypeConverter for "IValueConverter" does not support converting from a string" indicates that wpf didn't recognize string "languageConverter" as a converter

the same effect can be also achieved by using StringFormat property of Binding, without converter:

```
Text="{Binding Path=Key, StringFormat={x:Static res:Resources.lblCaption}}"
```