# Using two-way XAML Data Binding to convert a list of enum entries to a corresponding group of checkboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter

In my XAML, I have the following stackpanel containing a checkboxes for each weekday:

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox>Monday</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox>Tuesday</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox>Wednesday</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox>Thursday</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox>Friday</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox>Saturday</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox>Sunday</CheckBox>
</StackPanel>
```

In my code-behind, I have a class instance containing the field: `List<DaysOfTheWeek> TriggerDays`.

Whenever the user clicks a checkbox, I would like the `TriggerDays` field to update accordingly (i.e. either add or remove the user choice). Or when the field changes from somewhere else in the program, the correct checkboxes should either check or uncheck.

I achieved the wanted results by adding a unique field for each weekday to the class, i.e `public bool MondayChecked`, `public bool ThuesdayChecked`, but this is obviously a super-sloppy solution and not scalable.

I suspect that the solution lies in using some kind of conversion. However, I was not able to make sense of the Microsoft documentation for `IValueConverter` (I am new to XAML and WPF in general).

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enum binding with converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574793/enum-binding-with-converter)

Comment: @kfordt: What makes you think using a converter would me more "scalable" than using a source property for each checkbox?

Comment: @mm8: In the case that I did not just have 7 checkboxes, but perhaps multiple 100. This would necessiate adding a 100 different field each invoking the PropertyChangedEventHandler. It just seems that there would be some way of achieving it more elegantly, but I don't know.